# Grab img filename from id using Selenium RC

Tags: selenium-rc

I'm trying to grab the image filename - my webpage, based on inputs, is loading on of several images and I want to grab the filename of the image.  If I know the id or the alt-text, can I grab the image filename?  Right now, I'm using "get_html_source" (python, btw) and parsing it from there.  Is there an alternative, or is selenium not really built for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `get_attribute`:

```
sel.get_attribute('//path/to/my/img@src')
```